# Possible to layer a KonvaJS Stage/canvas on top of another canvas?

Tags: konvajs

Newbie question, maybe.

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:inline; border: 1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>
 </div>
```

What I want to do is place a KonvaJS Stage on top of (i.e. higher on the z-axis) `myCanvas` above.

If I use the default code:

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'myDiv',
       width: window.innerWidth,
       height: window.innerHeight
});
```

The Stage is placed inline after `myCanvas`.

Is there a way to tell Konva to layer its canvas?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a container for the stage into your `myDiv`:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:inline; border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Then create a stage a place it on top of the absolute position.

```
const myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: myCanvas.width,
  height: myCanvas.height
});

stage.container().style.position = 'absolute';
stage.container().style.top = '0';
stage.container().style.left = '0';
// add z-index if you need it
```